# How to integrate RSA with AS DS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, rsa, securid

I have not been able to find anything online that isn't AD FS. Since I do not run AD FS, is there a way to integrate RSA Securid with just AD DS? Any online resources? Also, this is a 2012 server.

Comment: Typically the RSA dual factor authentication is done using the RADIUS protocol, so look in your documentation for that. For the Windows Azure [Multi-Factor Authentication Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394299.aspx) it appears fairly easy to configure.

Comment: That isn't really true. RADIUS is optional and not preferred unless you have clients that can only do RADIUS. You simply add your Active Directory as an identity source in the appropriate security realm, using a service account. Configure the users DN for LDAP searches. It's not difficult... all you have to do is read the documentation for Authentication Manager.